# C# Regular Expressions, string between single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

```
string val = "name='40474740-1e40-47ce-aeba-ebd1eb1630c0'";
```

i want to get the text between `'` quotes using Regular Expressions.

Can anyone?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
string val = "name='40474740-1e40-47ce-aeba-ebd1eb1630c0'";

Match match = Regex.Match(val, @"'([^']*)");
if (match.Success)
{
    string yourValue = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(yourValue);
}
```

Explanation of the expression `'([^']*)`:

```
 '    -> find a single quotation mark
 (    -> start a matching group
 [^'] -> match any character that is not a single quotation mark
 *    -> ...zero or more times
 )    -> end the matching group
```

Comment: it's very helpful explanation. But why group[1]?

Comment: @liang The first group (`match.Groups[0]`) will contain the full string that is matched by the entire regex. That means that it also contains the leading quotation character. `match.Groups[1]` contains the first matching group in the regex, so that is the value we want to use.

Comment: Didn't know about Groups, but thats exactly what helps a lot ! +1

Answer (score 3):

You are looking to match GUID's in a string using a regular expression.

This is what you want, I suspect!

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(
  "(\\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-"+
  "([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\\}{0,1})",RegexOptions.CultureInvariant|RegexOptions.Compiled);

Match m = regex.Match(lineData);
if (m.Succes)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will extract the text between the *first* and *last* single quote on a line:

```
string input = "name='40474740-1e40-47ce-aeba-ebd1eb1630c0'";
Regex regName = new Regex("'(.*)'");
Match match = regName.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
{
    string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
    //do something with the result
}
```

Comment: if you had 'a', 'b' this one would get a single string of "a', 'b" rather than the probably intended "a".  @Fredrik's will do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use positive lookahead and lookbehind also,

```
string val = "name='40474740-1e40-47ce-aeba-ebd1eb1630c0'";

Match match = Regex.Match(val, @"(?<=')[^']*(?=')");
if (match.Success)
{
    string yourValue = match.Groups[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(yourValue);
}
```