# C# regex need help removing text from quotes

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Regular Expressions, string between single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662834/c-sharp-regular-expressions-string-between-single-quotes)

I need to pull out text from inside single quotes in C#.

The string I need to pull from is as follows:

```
User Entered 'Some Text Here'
```

I want to strip out all the other text and quotes and take only the text inside the single quotes to store in a new string so I can do a string compare:  `Some Text Here`

Comment: Do you not have access to the source of the text? What if the user enters a single quote?

Comment: And you tried...?

Comment: @Otiel. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11121629/601179

Comment: @gdoron Why did you just link to the current question...?

Comment: @SpikeX. I answered his question... This is what he have tried. `:)`

Comment: @gdoron Sarcastic comments like that confuse users who come to this post in the future looking for help (from Google, for example). I'd advise against it in the future.

Comment: @SpikeX. Well... I don't believe it can help anyone in the future. It's low quality too localized not a real question all together.

Answer (score 4):

The regex would be `'(.+?)'`. How you use that, I'll leave up to you, since you didn't show any evidence of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern `'([^']+)` and fetch the capture group.

For example:

```
Regex.Match(" User Entered 'Some Text Here'", @"'([^']+)").Groups[1].Value
```

Will return the text you desire.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it without regex (just an option):

```
string test = "this is 'a test 'of a string 'between quotes'.";
string[] tokens = test.Split(new char[] { '\'' });
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; ++i)
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        Console.Write(tokens[i]);
```

Output:

> a test between quotes

Comment: Regex would do this with less lines of code and less overhead.