# C# string match based on wildcards

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am getting some database exception like

`Database 'db_name' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore`

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if(ex.Message.Contains("Database 'db_name' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore")){
   //show user friendly message
  }
}
```

But the problem is we have around 10-15 database names and we will be keep adding more.

How do i match a string that has a wildcard?

Is there any regex to match something like `Database '{whatevercomes}' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore`

Comment: There most definitely is, have you tried to write any? Doesn't the exception give a numeric code you can check?

Comment: If you can, see if you can catch a more specific type of `Exception`, instead of parsing the message. Exception messages may be different on systems running a different language.

Comment: Have you searched for "regex between apostrophes"? I doubt that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662834/c-sharp-regular-expressions-string-between-single-quotes

Comment: btw, searching for 'cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore' should be enough.

Comment: If this is a `SqlException` you should it's [`Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx) property to dtermine the type.

Comment: Problem is, we are not able to reproduce this in dev environment. It happens only in live and we do restore only in LIVE. So I am not sure what is the sql exception i will get, so trying to check the error message

Comment: I do wonder why a user friendly message needs to know that much detail about why an exception occurred. Most users just want to be told something has gone wrong and be assured that somebody is fixing it. You should then be logging details of the exception somewhere for the devs/admins to be worrying about and they should not be at all friendly...

Comment: @Billa: Perhaps you should run some restores on your dev environment too, so you can test this reliably...

Answer (score 3):

You should handle only the `SqlException` instead of all exceptions. Then differentiate between the errors via the [`Number` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx). Your error is **927**.

Here you find all: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937592(v=sql.80).aspx

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(SqlException ex)
{
    if(ex.Number == 927)
    {
        //show user friendly message
    }
}
```

According to the actual name of the database: It seems not to be possible to retrieve it from the `SqlException`. Since the message could also change due to localization, why can't you handle this exception where you've opened the connection? Then you could simply use the [`SqlConnection.DataBase`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.database(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Connection-String"))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        // ...
    } catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string database = con.Database;
        if (ex.Number == 927)
        {
            //show user friendly message
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Could not open database '{0}' since it's currently restoring. Please inform your database administrator."
                                               , database);
            MessageBox.Show( errorMessage );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of regex just use this

```
 if(ex.Message.IndexOf("Database ") == 0 && ex.Message.Contains(" cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore") == true)
 {
      //user friendly message here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `Database '(.*?)' cannot be opened\. It is in the middle of a restore`

Usage:

```
var regex = @"Database '(.*?)' cannot be opened\. It is in the middle of a restore";
var match = Regex.Match(msg, regex);
if (match .Success)
{
    var databaseName = match.Groups[1].Value; 
    // Show messgage
}
```

But you should not parse the exception text but only look at the exception type and the `Number` property as mentioned in another question. (Reason: What if your application is executed on an operation system with another language?)

Comment: It is good. But what about if the message string is occured somewhere in the middle. How can i use this reg ex to Contain, instead of always starts with `Database` string?

Comment: Start and end the regex with `.*?` but `.` does not match line feed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help you or not. Instead of trying regex, what if you use two separate condition to achieve that

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  if(ex.Message.StartsWith("Database") && ex.Message.Contains(" cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore")){
   //show user friendly message
  }
}
```