# How to delete text in single quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have an element in my List with looks like this : `MalID='test'` .

What would be the best way to delete `test` in single quotes ?

I have tried to add the element from `List` in to a `string` and use Regex.

```
string MalID = fullLine[0];  //MalID='test'
Match malMatch = Regex.Match(MalID, @"'([^']*)"); // The result is 'test'
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Regular Expressions, string between single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662834/c-sharp-regular-expressions-string-between-single-quotes)

Comment: generally there is no best way because it depends on too many factors which are not mentioned in the question

Comment: @PatrickHofman , Sorry , i have edited the question. But it was answered. I will be more specific next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace()`:

```
string str = "MalID = 'test'";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "'.+?'", "''");
```

The result will be `MalID = ''`.

If you don't want `''` in result change `"''"` to `""`.

Comment: Thank you this works  and sorry i will be more specific next time i ask something !

Comment: @Boninseg `MalID = Regex.Replace(MalID, "MalID='.+?'", "MalID=''")` is a bit more reliable if there are more `'` in the string

Comment: @Slai, thanks, can I add it to my answer. Don't you mind?

Comment: sure you can use it. Just the `str.Replace(Regex.Match())` seems a bit unusual to me instead of just `Regex.Replace()`