# Regex expression -string between first and last single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I have some strings. I want total string between first and last single quote 
for example:

```
string val = "'Scale['#13212']'";   //--->Scale['#13212']
string val2= "'Scale[#13212']";     //--->Scale[#13212
string val3="abc'23'asad";          //--->23
```

I have use the following `regex-@".*'(.*?)'.*"` but it only displays string between last two.

for example:

```
string val = "'Scale['#13212']'";   //--->]
```

It is working fine with greedy when I use to capture the whole value of a string and a group(in group[1] ONLY) enclose with **a pair of single quote**
But when I want to capture the whole value of a string and a group(in group[1] ONLY) enclose with **multiple pair of single quote** , it only capture the value of string enclose with **last pair** but not the string between first and last single quotes.

for example:

```
string val1 = "Content:abc'23'asad";          //--->23
            string val2 = "Content:'Scale['#13212']'ta";

            Match match1 = Regex.Match(val1, @".*'(.*)'.*");
            Match match2 = Regex.Match(val2, @".*'(.*)'.*");
            if (match1.Success)
            {
                string value1 = match1.Value;
                string GroupValue1 = match1.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(value1);
                Console.WriteLine(GroupValue1);

                string value2 = match2.Value;
                string GroupValue2 = match2.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(value2);
                Console.WriteLine(GroupValue2);

                Console.ReadLine();

                // using greedy For val1 i am getting perfect value for-
                // value1--->Content:abc'23'asad
                // GroupValue1--->23

                // BUT using greedy For val2 i am getting the string elcosed by last single quote-
                // value2--->Content:'Scale['#13212']'ta
                // GroupValue2---> ]
                // But i want GroupValue2--->Scale['#13212']
            }
```

Please help!

Comment: The answer is in [this linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662956/3832970).

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 2):

Just use greedy `.*` between quotes:

```
'(.*)'
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%28.*%29%27&i=string+val+%3d+%22%27Scale%5b%27%2313212%27%5d%27%22%3b%0d%0astring+val2%3d+%22%27Scale%5b%2313212%27%5d%22%3b++%0d%0astring+val3%3d%22abc%2723%27asad%22%3b+++++++)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Positive Lookbehind and Positive Lookahead to take the text between the quotes ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhX84c/1))

```
(?<=\').*(?=\')
```

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
string test= "'$get this$' test value";
string getvalue = Regex.Match(test, @"\'(.*?)\'").Groups[1].ToString();
```